# ffmpeg read the current segmentation file

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm developing a system using ffmpeg to store some ip camera videos.
i'm using the segmentation command for store each 5 minutes a video for camera.
I have a wpf view where i can search historycal videos by dates. In this case i use the ffmpeg command concat to generate a video with the desire duration.
All this work excelent, my question is: it's possible concatenate the current file of the segmentation? i need for example, make a serch from the X date to the current time, but the last file is not generated yet by the ffmpeg. when i concatenate the files, the last one is not showing because is not finish the segment.

I hope someone can give me some guidance on what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some video formats can always be playable during the build process. That is, you can make a copy of the unfinished segmentation directly and use it to merge.

I suggest you use `flv` or `ts` format to do this. `mp4` is not supported. Also note that there is a delay from encoding to actually writing to the disk.

I'm not sure if direct copy will cause some data problems at the end of the segmentation file, but ffmpeg will ignore this part of the data during the merge process, so the merged video should be fine.

Comment: my problem is that i'm using mp4, i'll try with flv or ts format.

Comment: i changed the container format to .ts and now is working perfect!